# HTML layout problem in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, internet-explorer-7

I have some html:

```
<body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="left">
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="titlebar">
          <span id="date">Novermber 13, 3414</span>
          <span id="title"> The importance of being earnest.</span>
          <span id="author">HG Wellwhocares</span>
        </div>
        <iframe id="memo" />
        <div id="attachments"></div>
        <p id="description"></p>
        <div id="action">
          <div id="accept">Accept</div>
          <div id="revise">Revise</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And some css:

```
#container{
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gray;
}
#left{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1%;
}
#left:after{
  clear: both;
}
#content{
  margin-left: 22%;
  background: silver;
  padding: 3em;
}
#titlebar{
  text-align: center;
}
#date{
  float: left;
}
#title{
  clear: both;
}
#author{
  float: right;
}
#memo{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

There is also this jQuery:

```
  months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
  $(document).ready(function(){
    items = new Array();
    $.getJSON('_vti_bin/listdata.svc/BOTMemos?$orderby=MeetingDate', function(data){
      date = "";
      $.each(data.d.results, function(index, value){
        if(value.MeetingDate!=null){
          if(value.MeetingDate!=date){
            if(date!=""){
              $('#left').append('<hr />');
            }
            item = new Array(value.MeetingDate, value.Title0, value.Checkers);
            date = value.MeetingDate;
            month = months[parseInt(date.substring(5,7), 10)-1];
            formattedDate = month + " " + date.substring(8,10) + ", " + date.substring(0, 4);
            $('#left').append('<h1>'+formattedDate+'</h1>');
          }
          $('#left').append('<h2 class="memo">'+value.Title0+'</h2>');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Which result in two different layouts, this in ie9:
[image: Internet Explorer 9 render of page]
And this in ie7:
[image: Internet Explorer 7 render of page]
My two questions are:

1. Why does the text not show up on the left hand side in ie7?
2. Why do the three `<span>` tags in the `#titlebar` div not display side by side in ie7 like they do in ie9?

Comment: +1 for nice clear and clean question, that would be even better if you simulate it in jsFiddle.net

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? is your IE9 version in compatibility mode?

Comment: Future reference, IE9 (and I think IE7) has developer tools that allow you to see the page how the browser sees it. You should be able to hit F12 to bring it up. That can help you visualize why one of them acts differently than the other.

Comment: @valipour: I was thinking about it, but I'm writing this Microsoft Sharepoint, which does some weird stuff with default doctype, and I didn't want it rendering any differently than it would.

Comment: @Ash: It was not in compatibility mode, and IE9 was performing as expected, it was ie7 that was causing the issues.

Comment: @Shauna: That's actually what I used to take a picture in ie7.

Comment: @Vap0r: Did you checked the answer I gave you?

Comment: IE9 does not work like IE8 which doesn't work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE6 and none of them work like any other far more modern browser.

Comment: The DOCTYPE is important; IE in particular will render badly without a doctype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:left` for date, author and title `span` like this

```
#titlebar span {
    float:left;
}
```

and for text justification use this code also add width:

```
#date {
    text-align: left;
    width: 33%;
}
#title{
    text-align: center;
    width: 34%;
}
#author{
    text-align: right;
    width: 33%;
}
```

See the Demo in IE7 with updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Jy7Sz/

EDITED:

Replace this code with the above:

```
#date{
  float: left;
}

#title{
  clear: both;
}

#author{
  float: right;
}
```

EDITED: Answer Updated

Comment: Then how would I get the date to left justify, the title to center justify, and the author to right justify?

Comment: See the updated answer with your requirements and updated link as well.

Comment: [This](http://i55.tinypic.com/347ekg8.png) is what resulted from your fix. So it didn't work quite like it should.

Comment: Now it is fixed as you require by using `float:left` and `width:33%` for each span. See updated answer.

Comment: Ahh, that's actually almost perfect. I'm going to mark you as the answer, but [this](http://i54.tinypic.com/2lxw22x.png) is the result. Do you know how to move the `#author` to the very right edge of the iframe?

Comment: It is due to 99% width, as I give 33% width to each span. Still 1 percent is remaining. For this you need to remove the width from span and add it to date, title & author as I updated in my answer.

Comment: @AhsanRathod let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2161/discussion-between-vap0r-and-ahsan-rathod)

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do the three  tags in the #titlebar div not display side by side in ie7 like they do in ie9?
   You need to give them a width:
   like

   #titlebar span{
         width:33%;
               float:left;
       }

You need to make a new stylesheet for ie7+ ie8 in your header. They render stuff differently and not everything is supported

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie-fixes.css">

<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Giving them a width did not work, it gave them the width, but they didn't fall in line. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

1) There isn't anything displayed because you have nothing inside of your `#left` container.

```
<body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="left">
          <!-- Insert content here. -->
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="titlebar">
          <span id="date">Novermber 13, 3414</span>
          <span id="title"> The importance of being earnest.</span>
          <span id="author">HG Wellwhocares</span>
        </div>
        <iframe id="memo" />
        <div id="attachments"></div>
        <p id="description"></p>
        <div id="action">
          <div id="accept">Accept</div>
          <div id="revise">Revise</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

2) All divs without explicit width take up 100% of space in width.

```
#container{
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gray;
}
#left{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1%;
}
#left:after{
  clear: both;
}
#content{
  margin-left: 22%;
  background: silver;
  padding: 3em;
}
#titlebar{
  text-align: center;
}
#date {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#title {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;    
}
#author {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;   
}
#memo{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse the #left is emthy when you run it in fiddle you wont get a json respont....

Comment: Well then you should have given the code jQuery fetches and displays inside of it. If you put any code inside #left it will display properly however if you fetch something with your jQuery request that destroys the layout there is no way to tell whats the reason without sharing the content of the response. Its obvious that the response itself is guilty for making the container disappear.